# Xamarin.iOS, MVVMCross. Can I Access NavigationItem from TabBarController's root ViewController?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, mvvmcross

I use Xamarin.iOS and MVVMCross. My app's architecture is the following:

```
              +-----------------------+
              | RootViewModel         |
              | RootViewController    |
              | [MvxRootPresentation] |
              |                       |
              +--------+----+---------+
                       |    |
           +-----------+    +------------+
           |                             |
+----------+----------+      +-----------+---------+
|Tab1ViewModel        |      |Tab2ViewModel        |
|Tab1ViewController   |      |Tab2ViewController   |
|[MvxTabPresentation] |      |[MvxTabPresentation] |
|                     |      |                     |
+---------------------+      +---------------------+
```

The problem is, that the Navigation Bars are set up in the Tab ViewControllers.  I have to display some information on the NavigationItem.Title, which is stored in the RootViewModel. Can I have one, common Navigation Bar, which is initialize in the RootViewController?
Or if it's not possible, can I access RootViewModel from a TabViewController?

Comment: Do you have a property in the rootviewmodel for the navigation bar title? The tabViewModels could talk to the rootViewModel to change the title, Then just bind the navigationBar’s title to the property?

Answer (score 0):

1. In `RootViewController` add the decoration to the class.

```
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public partial class RootViewController : MvxTabBarViewController<RootViewModel>
```

2. In your tab controllers add the decoration:

```
[MvxTabPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = false, TabName = "Tab1Title", TabIconName = "Tab1Icon")]
public partial class Tab1ViewController : ViewController<Tab1ViewModel>
```

3. In your tab controllers also add this in `ViewDidLoad` to hide the indivdual navigation bars:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    if (NavigationController != null && NavigationController.NavigationBar != null)
    {
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Bonus. You can change the tab title translation in the `RootViewController`

```
protected override void SetTitleAndTabBarItem(UIViewController viewController, MvxTabPresentationAttribute attribute)
{
    attribute.TabName = _yourLocalizationService.Translate(attribute.TabName);
    base.SetTitleAndTabBarItem(viewController, attribute);
}
```